# Do while loops execute all lines of code if their conditional is no longer met in the middle of a block?

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and I had a question for a project I'm working on.

So if I run this code, does the while loop exit after sending the string "world" to the terminal? Or would it exit before that code is ran?

```
while (conditionalStatement == false) 
{
   std::cout << "hello ";
   conditionalStatement = true;
   std::cout << "world\n";

}
```

Edit:

When I run the code above it sends hello world to terminal. However, I have another few lines of code that are giving me some different results. Not sure why.

My project is setup basically like this and when I run it, the string "we broke the loop!" Isn't being sent to the terminal when the user inputs 2.

```
bool something = false;
while (something == false)
{

    std::cout << "choose 2 to break loop.\n";

    int loopbreak;
    std::cin >> loopbreak;

    if (loopbreak == 1)
        {
         std::cout << "were looping!\n";
        } 
    else if (loopbreak == 2) 
        {
        something = true;
        std::cout << "we broke the loop!\n";
        }

}
//continue code
```

Comment: Did you run the code? What happened?

Comment: It has to encounter the comparison in the conditional test to know that the `while` should stop. If you want it to stop earlier, you would add an additional test (an `if`) and use `break`.

Comment: The condition only gets evaluated at the top of each iteration of the loop; it is used to decide whether to execute the body of the loop (again) or not.

Comment: I updated my question with some new code to clarify why I'm confused on this. 


I did run the original code I asked about, and it runs as explained from the two other answers, but im now more confused why my project isn't working like that.

Comment: This `while (something = false)` _assigns_ `false` to `something` rather than testing it. Same for your two tests of `loopbreak`.

Comment: Exiting (or going to the next iteration) in the middle of a loop body is what the `break` and `continue` statements are for (though they should be used with caution, so as to keep the code readable). Note that instead of `something == false`, it's more idiomatic to write `! something`. For non-boolean values, [yoda conditions](//stackoverflow.com/q/10076689/90527) can help catch accidental assignment if your compiler isn't already warning you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The condition is only checked at the start of each loop iteration.  If you want to end loop execution early, you must execute a `break` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a bit foolish because my code was indeed sending the correct string to terminal. This was actually because of an issue where I was accidentally sending a system("cls"); command after the loop was broken. *homer doh noise*  Your answers helped me figure out the true problem after a few days. Thanks!!